# What this error tells in mysql query..?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

```
$this->db->select('FORMAT(SUM(TotalValue),2) as TotalValue');
$this->db->from('ospos_zreads_pdf');
```

When I use this query in codeigniter and when I am going to run, this shows below query and goes some wrong. Where I did mistake?

```
SELECT FORMAT(SUM(TotalValue), `2)` as TotalValue FROM (`ospos_zreads_pdf`);
```

Comment: Try `$this->db->select('your expression ',FALSE);`

Comment: Thanks for reply but as I need SUM and also want to make number till two decimal that is FORMAT. @ M Khalid Junaid

Comment: Check what query is prepared using `$this->db->last_query();`

Comment: What is a text of the error message?

Comment: @syed suleman: It does not prepare any query as it fires same error which I have mentioned.

Comment: Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as TotalValue FROM (`ospos_zreads_pdf`)

Comment: When I put query like this in mysql, SELECT FORMAT(SUM(TotalValue), 2) as TotalValue FROM (`ospos_zreads_pdf`); 

It not shows any error.... The error in `2`.

So, How can I write in codeigniter?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove backquotes sign near about 2 as per below-

```
SELECT FORMAT(SUM(TotalValue), 2) as TotalValue FROM (`ospos_zreads_pdf`);
```

Comment: Thanks Zafar Malik but this can be possible in mysql query. I want in codeigniter as it shows tilt sign.

Comment: @ViralBhoot read first comment on your question you need to pass false in `select()`'s 2nd parameter so CI will not add bacticks

Answer (score 0):

As per, M Khalid Junaid, I got solution for my question. Thanks @M Khalid Junaid..

```
$this->db->select('FORMAT(SUM(TotalValue),2) as TotalValue',FALSE);
$this->db->from('ospos_zreads_pdf');
```